# Morera's Theorem in Several Variables

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open set and  $f: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ be continious. If
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma f(z) {\rm d} z=0
\end{align}
for every closed piecewise curve $\gamma \in D$, then $f(z)$ is analytic on $D$.

I am looking for a similar statement for the complex-valued functions of several variables.
A reference would be good too.

Comment: A function of several variables is analytic iff it is analytic in each variable separatly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood%27s_lemma So I guess you can ask $\int_\gamma f(z_1,\cdots,z_n)dz_1\cdots dz_n =0$ for any curve $\gamma \subset D \subset \mathbb{C}^n$

Comment: @AlexL   Great. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexL If $\gamma$ is a curve I don't know what $\int_\gamma f(z_1,z_2)\,dz_1dz_2$ even _means_, much less what it has to do with the classical Morera theorem.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  I thought he meant that Osgood lemma implies that we only need to check every coordinate with a single-variable version of Morera's theorem. By the way,I know that there is multivariable version. I just don't know what to integrated over.

Comment: @Boby Yes, that's what it sounds like he's saying. Can _you_ tell me what that has to do with $\int_\gamma f(z_1,z_2,)\,dz_1dz_2$? Or what that notation even _means_???